# Fogbugz API Rich Text sEvent

Tags: xml, api, fogbugz

There was a past post from 5 years ago [FogBugz -- Case detail (rich text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790225/fogbugz-case-detail-rich-text) that stated that Fogbugz API does not support rich text.  Does that still stand true today? I able to do plain text fairly easily using sEvent query param.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get back the rich text as raw HTML by specifying the `sHTML` field as one of your `cols` (see http://help.fogcreek.com/8202/xml-api#Sample_XML_Payloads). The `sFormat` field will be "html" if it's rich text.

It doesn't look like you can use the API to create rich text entries yet, but it might be worth experimenting with using HTML similar to what is returned to see if does the job.